# Phonegap 2.1 iOS : reading file in app www folder

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I try to read a file in my iOS app (phonegap 2.1 + jquerymobile) with Phonegap `getFile` function but I always have this error :

```
Error in error callback: File3 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

My file is in `www/data/datajson.txt` and contains some json data.

**My code:**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    //get www folder path
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    var pathwww = path;
    console.log(pathwww); /* /var/mobile/Applications/{ID}/{APPNAME}.app/www/ */
    fileSystem.root.getFile("file//"+pathwww+"data/datajson.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    // result : Error in error callback: File3 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
    pathwww.getFile("file///data/datajson.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    // result : Error in success callback: File2 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

I don't understand why I can't navigate in my `www` folder and read my `datajson.txt` file.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a text file from your app, you can just make an 'ajax' call to get it

```
        $.ajax({
        url : 'data/datajson.txt',
        type : "get",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('data loaded ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error loading data :' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

If you want to write files, you cannot write them to the same location as your app. You need to write them to your app's Document folder. This is created on installation so you cannot put files there in XCode. You would have to copy files there post-installation.

You get access to your app's Document folder when you call `window.requestFileSystem`

Comment: Hello, your solution work fine.
my target is to read, replace and create image, pdf, json files on my app folder. That's why i try to use getDirectory and getFile of phonegap library

Comment: You can't replace files in your app folder. You can only write to files in your app/Documents location.

Comment: thank you for this precision, i need to update files on my app (www/data/) like images or pdf,  how can i put this files on app/Documents location ? can i have access to this folder via xcode to put all files or this folder is just created on installation ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your HTML file is in your folder `www`, you may try the following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data", {create: true}).getFile("datajson.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Have a try and let me know if this works mate.

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. i have the same error : Error in error callback: File3 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object. 

console log full path of fileSystem.root = /var/mobile/Applications/{ID}/Documents

If i try "./data/datajson.txt" I suppose i was in /var/mobile/Applications/{ID}

On simulator, my app www folder was on
/var/mobile/Applications/{ID}/{appname.app}/

Comment: ok, wait I'll suggest you another solution... give me some secs mate

Comment: hey mate, I've just re-edited my post. Try the new solution and let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks, i try your solution on simulator.
this line :
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data", {create: true}).getFile("datajson.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);

Create a "data" folder on Applications/{ID}/Documents

But my folder and my file are in Applications/{ID}/AppName.app/www/

Comment: Ok, with this line i can go in my folder 
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("../AppName.app/www/data", {create: true}).getFile("datajson.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);

but i have this error message now:
 Error in success callback: File2 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Comment: this syntaxe works:
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("../AppName.app/www/data", {create: true},function(entry){entry.getFile("datajson.txt", {create: false}, gotFileEntry, failGetFile);});